# How to have a Singleton that works at runtime and design time in Delphi

Tags: delphi, singleton, components, delphi-xe2

Delphi XE2

I am newbie on component development.

I have a singleton class, "TThemeManager" that holds a colletion of pallete colors that I use on my application. Only one ThemeManager is necessary for the entire application and only one theme is used, there is a way to define which.

This class is created on the initialization section of the unit that declares it on a global variable:

```
var
  NaharThemeManager: TNaharThemeManager;

implementation
```

...

```
initialization  
  if Not Assigned(NaharThemeManager) then
    NaharThemeManager := TNaharThemeManager.Create;
```

That works fine on the application, it is always available.

Then I have created some components, using the Delphi Wizard for that, nothing special, I only added a property that I can select from the current Theme which color I want for that component.

```
  TNaharWEBPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
  private
    FThemeColor : TNaharPalleteColor;
    procedure   OnObserver(Sender: TObject; AParam, AValue: Variant);
    procedure   UpdateColor;
    procedure   SetColor(const Value: TNaharPalleteColor);
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
  published
    property    ThemeColor: TNaharPalleteColor read FThemeColor write SetColor default npcMainColor;
  end;
```

when setting the Theme Color:

```
procedure TNaharWEBPanel.SetColor(const Value: TNaharPalleteColor);
begin
  FThemeColor := Value;

  UpdateColor;
end;

procedure TNaharWEBPanel.UpdateColor;
begin
  if FThemeColor <> npcNone then
  begin
    Color := NaharThemeManager.CurrentPallete.Color[FThemeColor];

    Font.Color := NaharThemeManager.CurrentPallete.HighContrast(FThemeColor);
  end;
end;
```

That NaharThemeManager is the singleton class. Or should it be. However If I put several panels like this they do not use the same singleton. It seems to have one per component. I dont know how to debug this, so I could only see the evidence of the problem

And when I have the application running the singleton is not the same across the my components and the application.

What I have to do to trully have only one singleton of this object?

Comment: You **are** creating and using a singleton, so why do you think that each panel is using a different instance of the manager? How are you checking that? What you describe would only be possible if your project has multiple instances of the manager's unit in memory, and that should not be possible under normal conditions, otherwise you would be getting a "duplicate unit" exception raised.

Comment: I have an AddObserver on my singleton, where each of my visual components call ThemeManager.AddObserver(self). So the singleton will notify all the components if the theme was changed for example. I have created a non visual component only to show the information about this singleton and I have put a published property to show up the number of Observers added to the singleton, and it only shows up 1. And if I change the theme (by this non visual component) only one panel gets notified by the notify and change its color. I have many panels on the same TFrame, all should get notified.

Comment: Since you have not shown any of that code, I can only assume that your observer logic likely has a bug in it, for instance if it only keeps one registered observer and discards the others. If you want help, please provide an [SCCCE](http://sscce.org) showing everything you are doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You right, I rechecked my observer logic and it only register the first component, and after that ignores everything. This is why only one is notified. I fixed that and is now everything working. Singletong DOES work accross units on design mode. Thank you.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating and using a singleton, so each panel should be using the same instance of the manager.  What you describe would only be possible if your project has multiple instances of the manager's unit in memory, and that should not be possible under normal conditions, otherwise you would be getting a "duplicate unit" exception raised.

The more likely culprit is that your observer logic has a bug in it, such ass if it only keeps one registered observer and discards the others.